# How to work with the error class inside class

Tags: php, class, object

Ok, i got a error class, where you can do `$error->add($message);` which will store the $message to an array inside the class.

```
    private $_errorArray = array();

    public function add($message){
        $this->_errorArray[] = $message;
    }
    public function output(){
        return $this->_errorArray;
    }
    public function exists(){
        if(empty($this->_errorArray)){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Now what if i have a class AlbumMapper, that grabs and assigns variables. But if it cant grab (no rows to select), then it should add a message to this error.

```
class AlbumMapper {
    private $_pdo;

    function __construct($pdo){
        $this->_pdo = $pdo;
    }
    public function fetch($album){
        $columns = "id, title, uID, date";
        $table = TABLE_USERS_ALBUMS;
        $query = "SELECT ".$columns." FROM ".$table." WHERE id=:id";
        $query = $this->_pdo->prepare($query);
        $query->bindValue(":id", $album->id());
        $query->execute();

        if( ! $data = $query->fetch() ) { $errors->add("Album not exists"); }

        $album->assign($data);
    }
}
```

And, i would like to output the error OUTSIDE the class.
So:

```
$error = new errors();
$albumMapper->fetch($album);
if ( $error->exists() ) { $error->output(); }
```

I can make this work, if i pass the $error to the fetch() method, but then i would need to pass the $error to all my methods, and it dont feel the best way to do it.

I can also do this by creating the object inside the object $albumMapper, so in the constructor it does: `$error = new errors();` and then you can add the errors to this, but how would i output the errors then, if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is a stupid suggestion, but why aren't you using `Exceptions`?

The beautiful thing about `Exceptions` is that they bypass normal code flow so you don't have to worry about return values and such.

Comment: Does exceptions not show as real errors, like something is wrong with the site? I would like to output in plain "No albums exists" not "Exceptions has been catch: error ... on line ...".. If you could do that please show example

Answer (score 1):

You just need to globalize the error class so the function can use it. Inside your fetch function, on the first line, just define `$error` as global, like so:

```
public function fetch($album){
    global $error;
    $columns = "id, title, uID, date";
```

Although `$error` is not the greatest variable name to globalize somewhere. Also your `$errors->add()` line inside the function would need to be changed to `$error->add()`. This should work but I don't strongly recommend doing this.

Comment: I dont want to use global, i recently have recode hole my project for not being apart of the global variables..